# What is the relationship between the terms "airprox" and "near mid-air collision"?

Tags: safety, air-traffic-control, terminology

Do the terms "Airprox" and "Near mid-air collision" mean the same? If not what is the difference between them?

Comment: Where did you see these terms?

Answer (score 4):

A Near Mid Air Collision (NMAC) is an Aircraft Proximity (AIRPROX), but an AIRPROX is not necessarily an NMAC. NMAC is used by the FAA (see 7-6-3 in the [AIM](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/)), while AIRPROX is used by ICAO.

NMAC is empirically defined as coming within "100 feet vertically and 500 feet horizontally" of the other aircraft, whereas AIRPROX is categorized from A to D. The A to D categories are not empirically defined.

> A - Risk of collision.
>   B - Safety not assured.
>   C - No risk of collision.
>   D - Risk not determined.

---

References:

- [AIRPROX](https://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/AIRPROX) (skybrary.aero)
- [NMAC](https://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/NMAC) (skybrary.aero)

Answer (score 0):

AIRPROX is the phraseology recommended by ICAO, midair collision, close call and near miss can also be used, but not as a standard phraseology!

Comment: So under ICAO recommendations, if you collide with another plane and it's somehow not a mayday scenario, you don't say anything other than that you came close?